# Inconsistencies in TranslateAnimation distance with different duration

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

When dealing with TranslateAnimation, I do not understand what is happening, can anyone help?

Compare these two scenarios:

```
Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -7f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
slide.setDuration(5000);
```

and

```
Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -7f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
slide.setDuration(2000);
```

It is my understanding that these should both perform the exact same task over different times, i.e move a view left by 700% of its width, over 5 (or 2) seconds.

In reality, both pieces of code move the view left, but by different distances. Why is this, since it is constant in both scenarios, and how can it be avoided?

Comment: I tried both of animations and distance is the same. Provide more code.

Comment: Are you comparing two different devices? And is it the same view? Or two different views?

Comment: @Whitney The code refers to the same view on the same device

Comment: @Max77 I will provide a more complete example in a short while